# twilio incoming call event listener not called but ringing when i call my twilio number python flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, voice

Incoming event listener not called but ringing when i call in my number. Outgoing call is working properly. There seems to be problem only in incoming call. When i call in my number, it rings but doesn't call the incoming listener event. I read the documentation and many other solutions but it doesn't solve my problem. Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.
[this is where my problem lies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFGPi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not able to Add comment. So, writing as an answer.
It's one month old, you may have already figured it out. But, it may be helpful for someone in future.
Since you didn't provided the Device initialisation, it may be because of this.Below is the working solution.

1. Initialise the Twilio device with token

   device = new Twilio.Device(token, {
   codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
   fakeLocalDTMF: true,
   enableRingingState: true,
   debug: false,
   });
2. Incoming Call Event handling

   device.on("incoming", function(conn) {
   conn.accept() # Accept the call
   conn.reject() # Reject the call
   })

Hope this helps someone.